# Register elevated privileges on installation

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, uac

I'm currently creating an installer for a software I wrote. This software will be installed into the "Program Files" folder. Since the application also includes an updater, it will need to write to the "Program Files" from time to time. Currently I'm using a manifest-file which will always launch the application with elevated privileges, even though there might not be an update.

Just recently I discovered that applications like Steam can alter the "Program Files" without explicitly asking for elevated privileges due to a already elevated service running in the background.

Now I figured that at some point while installing Steam, this service did something so that it will always have the privileges needed.

Is it possible to create a registry entry that will handle something like that? And if yes, can anyone give me a hint on how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

A system service is part of the operating system when, like Steam, when
it runs under the LocalSystem Account. It then has unlimited permissions on the
computer (except for network access).

The usual method for installers such as yours is to divide the installation into
two:

1. A program running in normal mode that periodically checks for new version
   and downloads it, then calls-
2. A program to install the downloaded new version with elevated permissions.

This is the most user-friendly configuration, letting the user decide whether
to install now or later.

If you wish to install the update in the background without elevation prompt,
then in addition to the system-service approach (which isn't that simple)
you could instead use a scheduled job running with the highest privileges
of an administrator account.

Comment: I do understand the approach of seperating download and installation. But does a service get these privileges just because it is a service? Or is this service somewhere registered, so the operating system knows what privileges it should assign to it?

Comment: It all depends on the user account under which the service is running. The default Local System is not really an account, but has unlimited powers without needing elevation. If the service runs under a user account, it will have the permissions of the account.